# gwt g2d: drawImage in ie8

Tags: java, gwt, internet-explorer-8, drawing2d

I'm using g2d with gwt in order to implement some canvas functionalities. As the canvas implementation provided by gwt (I'm using version 2.4.0) is not supported by ie8, at least that is what I could experience, I decided to change to the before mentioned graphic library.

The issue arises when I try to draw a base64 image. I submit the following code:

```
Element img = DOM.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", imagen.getBase64());
ImageElement imgElement = ImageElement.as(img);
surface.drawImage(imgElement, x, y, w, h);
```

This works well in IE9, but it doesn't in IE8. Despite of drawing the image, surface puts a blank square.

As you probably know, g2d is an implementation of excanvas.js, and after invoking drawImage an 'invalid poninter' js error arises.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

As I could see into the javascript, I got the following error:

```
vmlStr.push(' ''>', '<g_vml_:image src="' + image.src + '"' , ..., ' />', 
'</g_vml_:group>');
```

This is part of excanvas.js code, just before finishing the drawing. What is retrieving "invalid pointer" error is image.src, it seems that the base64 is not being assigned to that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found an alternative that would fit for all browsers: generate image at server side and then encode it to base64, then it could be retrieved in a callback function to the client side.